# Why doesn't selecting a row in SQL Server return any NULL values?

Tags: sql-server, select, null, conditional-statements

I've got the following SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [TestID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TestNum] [int] NULL,
    [TestReason] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

So **TestNum** an **INT** which allows **NULL** values, and I've inserted a whole lot of data into the table, of which some of the rows contain a **NULL** value for **TestNum**

If I then run the following query

```
select *
from Test
where TestNum != 123
```

The query above doesn't return any rows that have a **NULL** value. I would expect it to return ALL rows EXCEPT those that have the value 123.

Why is this?

I am running this query on a MS-SQL 2000 DB, imported into MS SQL 2005. Does this have any effect? Or is this behaviour standard for all versions of MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NULL represents the value "unknown".  For this reason, NULL = NULL is false.  If you want to see NULLs, you have to also say "OR TestNum IS NULL".

Comment: +1. To add: This is not SQL Server that does so - this is standard SQL trinary semantics, the same basically on all SQL Servers. So, noone please blames Microsoft for that.

Comment: Thnx Strommy, TomTom and everyone else. It kinda makes sense, though I still disagree on such an implementation/definition.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE TestNum != 123 OR TestNum IS NULL
```

NULL values are treated differently from other values.
It is not possible to compare `NULL` and `123`; they are not equivalent.